# Spring security application can not redirect to CAS server login page

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, cas

I am using spring security 3.x, here i need to integrate with JA-SIG CAS server, I can login CAS server through https://localhost:8443/cas/login, but after integrated with spring security, i can not redirect my login page to CAS login URL, and my previous account doesn't use, spring security always tell me login error, googled for lots of times and don't know why? any help will be appreciated. And here is patial of my spring security configuration:

```
    <bean id="serviceProperties" class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
            <!-- 这里的service 必须是一个由CasAuthenticationFilter 监控的URL -->
            <property name="service" value="http://localhost:8082/dna/j_spring_cas_security_check" />
            <property name="sendRenew" value="false" />
        </bean>
        <!-- hook up cas entry point -->
        <bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
            <constructor-arg ref="casEntryPoint" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="casAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
            <property name="authenticationUserDetailsService">
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper">
                    <constructor-arg ref="myUserDetailsService" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
            <property name="ticketValidator">
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
                    <!-- 配置cas服务器前缀 -->
                    <constructor-arg index="0" value="https://localhost:8443/cas-server-webapp-5.0.8/" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="key" value="casAuthProviderKey" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="casFilter" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
            <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="casEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
            <property name="loginUrl" value="https://localhost:8443/cas-server-webapp-5.0.8/login" />
            <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="singleLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
            <constructor-arg value="https://localhost:8443/cas-server-webapp-5.0.8/cas/logout" />
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/j_spring_cas_security_logout" />
        </bean>

        <!-- 目前不需要将ajax请求拒绝 -->
        <bean id="authEntryPoint" class="com.gooalgene.common.authority.AjaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" c:loginFormUrl="/login" />
        <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.gooalgene.common.handler.AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl">
            <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/dna/index" />
        </bean>
        <sec:http auto-config='false' use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint">
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/managerPage" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
            <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
            <sec:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
                            authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
            <sec:access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
            <sec:custom-filter ref="casFilter" position="CAS_FILTER" />
            <sec:custom-filter ref="singleLogoutFilter" before="CAS_FILTER" />
            <sec:custom-filter ref="filterSecurityInterceptor" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR" />
        </sec:http>
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
    </sec:authentication-manager>
```

And my spring mvc default welcome page is `/login`.
Here is my debug console log:

```
INFO  [com.gooalgene.common.handler.AuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl]
- 登录失败，异常信息：No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
```

Comment: Can you please confirm what your CAS application name is? Is it just "cas" or "cas-server-webapp-5.0.8"

Comment: yeah, the latter is right. i can login such cas server through `https://localhost:8443/cas-server-webapp-5.0.8/login`